# Is there a way to use jQuery functions if they are not defined in the `$(document),ready` function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have several scripts and the `$(document).ready` is being defined in another script. I tried defining functions in another file that make use of JQuery syntax but they don't work. Is there a way to use jQuery functions if they are not defined in the `$(document),ready` function?

Here is my first script. it's just a ready block (yes its empty):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 
});
```

This is my second script:

```
function editPage() {
    $("#mybutton").click(function() {
       alert("Clicked"); 
    });
    
}

editPage();
```

It does not work.

The second code does not work. They are in different files. The first script is always loaded. I have the jquery library defined. If i place the `click` code in the first script, it works.

This is ASP.NET MVC 5

Comment: Without providing a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, it is hard for anyone to help troubleshoot this without guessing

Comment: We need to see your actual code to understand your issue, and what you're asking. If I've understood you correctly, then you can define a `function() {}` block anywhere. You only need to *call* it from within a document.ready handler if the logic of the function relies on elements being available within the DOM.

Comment: Can we call it out of document.ready handler?

Comment: Yes, so long as the `#mybutton` element exists in the DOM when you call the `editPage()` function. This is the entire point of the document.ready handler, and why it's necessary. If you want to avoid using it, you could just place your JS code at the end of the page, just before `</body>`

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correct, as long as you reference JS file earlier, you can use it in all other files which is coming later in sequence.

In following scenario, you can use Jquery in "your-test-file.js"

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/your-test-file.js"></script>
```